Is it true that a sine wave is the only signal that does not change shape in a linear circuit?
This is from Microelectronic Circuits by Adel Sedra and Kenneth Smith.
The book says,

In fact, the sine wave is the only signal that does not change shape
as it passes through a linear circuit.

Is this always true? I think this is only true if there are no two frequencies in the frequency response of the linear circuit (says an amplifier) that have the same magnitude (gain). Otherwise, the sum of two sinusoidal signals at different frequencies would be non-sinusoidal and would not have the same shape as the input.
\begin{align*}
v_i &= A_1 \sin(\omega_1 t) + A_2 \sin(\omega_2 t) \\
v_o &= A v_i = A \left( A_1 \sin(\omega_1 t) + A_2 \sin(\omega_2 t) \right)
\end{align*}


so you're not making a distinction between A sinewave and the SUM OF TWO sine waves?

@Neil_UK I think so, for example  if you look at the plot of 2 sin(2 t) + sin(5 t) it doesn't have a sine shape.  Also, if you don't distinguish that, then every periodic signal from the Fourier series can be expressed as a sum of sine waves.

I think you might’ve misunderstood Neil_UK’s comment. It’s always true with a single sine wave input, which is the point of the textbook snippet. It says nothing about sums of sine waves. I think you’re mistakenly applying superposition to the observation of “keeps the same shape”. Applying a sum of 2 or more sine waves to the linear system will result in a distorted shape, unless the gain and phase responses are exactly the same at those frequencies (like you hinted at).

Not only your counterexample, there are obviously certain linear circuits that can pass any signal without distortion (for example, a voltage divider) ..so refer to Photon's answer.  The word "any" should be in there.

It would be more correct to say,
"A sine wave is the only signal that does not change shape as it passes through any linear circuit"
Why? Because given some other signal shape, (for example a sum of two sine waves) it's possible we can construct a linear circuit that won't change its shape. But if we start with a sine wave, there's no linear circuit that will change its shape.

A single sinewave will not change its shape through a linear circuit. It may change its amplitude, or its phase however, neither of which change the shape.
A signal composed of two or more sinewaves of different frequencies may, or may not, change its shape, depending on the frequency response of the linear network. If the network has a different gain or phase shift at each of the incoming frequencies, then the relative amplitude and phase of those individual sinewaves will be altered, and the outgoing signal shape will be different. In general, a linear filter will alter the shape of a signal composed of several sinewaves.

All signals are sums of multiple sine waves at different frequencies, except a sine wave itself which is not a sum of multiple sine waves at different frequencies, however it could be a sum of two sine waves with same frequencies but different phases to create a new sine wave with a phase offset.
So this is why a shape of e.g. square wave changes because the relative amplitudes of the different sine waves change, but a shape of single sine wave does not change.
A sum of two sine waves at different frequencies is not a sine wave.

If you scale all of the harmonics of any periodic waveform by the same real value, then it is true that the sum of those harmonics would have the same shape as the original. Consequently, scaling the many sinusoidal harmonics by the same amount, without altering their phase, will not change the wave shape at all.
Below are three sinusoid sources \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$, all having different phase with respect to each other, and different amplitudes. We scale and add them, but we don't change any individual phase:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
\$V_{OUT1}\$ (blue) is their simple sum, and \$V_{OUT2}\$ (orange) is the result of scaling each by the same amount, and then summing:

The input and output waveforms have the same shape.
However, this does not account for phase shifts. Individual harmonics may be (and usually are) subject to different amounts of phase shifts, on their way through a system, and even if that system had a flat (constant) gain across the spectrum, if it phase shifts any of those harmonics differently from any any others, the wave shape will be changed. Here I add 60° to the second harmonic, source B, using another source V5:

simulate this circuit
Now the summed output waveforms look very different:

If the input were a simple sinusoid, with no harmonics, the output from a linear system will always be a sinusoid, but it may be phase shifted or amplified. This is because a phase shifted sinusoid is still a sinusoid. This is how the author is able to claim that a solitary sinusoid is the only input wave shape that is guaranteed to traverse a linear system, and still emerge at the output with the same shape. Not necessarily the same amplitude or phase, but the same shape.
Is it true that a signal with multiple harmonics is always subject to a change of shape? Well, not if the system has a flat gain across the spectrum, then the signal will emerge with the same shape, but that's the only case I can think of. In technical terms, such a system's transfer function is purely real, like the constant \$K=1.5\$ I used in my examples.
Strictly speaking, the following is a linear circuit, but the output will have exactly the same shape as any input:

simulate this circuit
To be pedantic, I would disagree with the statement "a sine wave is the only signal that does not change shape in a linear circuit". This and any number of other flat-gain circuits are counter-examples, for which the sinusoid is not the only waveform. It would be more correct to say that the sine wave input is the only shape that is guaranteed not to change shape in all cases.


Is this always true?

No.
In fact, make that NO.
There are many different types of signals: audio, video, telephone, radio, industrial control sensors, radar, wifi, . . .  While no single circuit can process all of them perfectly, a well-designed circuit for any of those categories can be so close to perfect that the difference or distortion is irrelevant (or unmeasureable).  For example, a high-end audio test set can measure harmonic distortion down to less than 0.001% - way below anything anyone can hear - and these distortion measurements apply to complex audio waveforms just as well as pure sinewave test tones.
There is a second reason the statement (and the thinking behind it) is incorrect.  There is nothing magical about a sinewave signal.  The idea that only a signal with no harmonics can be amplified perfectly could be interpreted to mean that a pure sinewave signal is somehow immune to harmonic distortion being added to it in an amplifier circuit.  Not so.  While a clean sinewave signal is used to measure distortion, that proves that a sine signal is capable of circuit-induced distortions.

A circuit that produces harmonic distortion is not a linear circuit.

So you're saying that in all of recorded human history there never has been created a linear circuit?  Really?

There are also no real devices that follow Ohm's Law, no perfect resistance-free wires, and no ideal voltage sources. Nonetheless the abstraction of ideal devices/circuits/systems is useful to study and some devices/circuits/systems perform close enough to ideal for engineering purposes.
